# Twitter bootstrap center div in parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a website for a restaurant and on the menu page there are sometimes menu items that enter a new row. To make it look better I want those to be horizontally centered but for some reason nothing has worked so far. This is my code.

https://gyazo.com/20ec303347879fad3baa009a51391ee0 token=96579347b3eabb03b27ab752294c8ed0

(that is a screenshot of the layout and the last one is on the left but i need it in the center. I already tried "text-center and justify content center. I also just tried to make the div 12 instead of 4 but that ruins the description since that becomes wider that the rest.)

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 border-bottom mb-5">
        <h4 class="font-weight-bold"> Cocktails</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            if (count($arrDrinksCocktails)) {
                foreach ($arrDrinksCocktails as $item) {
                    ?>
                    <div class = "col-sm-4 text-center menu-item-box cocktails">
                        <h5 class = "font-weight-bold"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></h5>
                        <p class = "m-0"><?php echo $item['price']; ?></p>
                        <span><?php echo $item['desc']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
        <?php
            if (count($arrDrinksCocktails2)) {
                foreach ($arrDrinksCocktails2 as $item) {
                    ?>
                    <div class = "col-sm-4 text-center menu-item-box drinks">
                            <h5 class = "font-weight-bold"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></h5>
                            <p class = "m-0"><?php echo $item['price']; ?></p>
                            <span><?php echo $item['desc']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>  
    </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Daan, welcome to SO. To help you we need you to be more specific. We don't know your code so walk us through it. Explain what part you are referring to and the problems you encountered when trying to create a solution. Also tell us what you have already tried. Another very helpful aid for us to help you is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to tinker with. Succes!

Comment: https://gyazo.com/20ec303347879fad3baa009a51391ee0?token=96579347b3eabb03b27ab752294c8ed0 (that is a screenshot of the layout and the last one is on the left but i need it in the center. I already tried "text-center and justify content center. I also just tried to make the div 12 instead of 4 but that ruins the description since that becomes wider that the rest.)

Comment: Okay, that helps. Add it to your original question above so others can see it as well.

Comment: Please provide sample code in HTML form in a case likes this. No one here has your server-side setup and data available, so you are placing the bar for re-creating a working example unnecessarily high by showing the PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          lorem Ipsum
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          lorem Ipsum
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You have to use `justify-content-center` on the row itself! So then the columns will get the CSS. For further knowledge you can go through the below links

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/